# Polymer iron list with position fixed element content hidden behind

Tags: html, polymer

Polymer iron list with position fixed element content hidden behind.

[1]: http://jsbin.com/ginakis/edit?html,output `click here`

Comment: Please explain what you want to see and what you got.

Comment: I have a peper-dropdown inside iron list,which has position fixed.paper-dropdown is hidden behind the ironlist. I want to see the paper-dropdown to be visible fully on top of the iron-list.

Comment: Line1,Line2,Line3 are visible Line4,Line5 are hidden. I want to see all text(Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4,Line5)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `iron-list`. `iron-list` puts default style `overflow:auto`, that is why some elements were hidden.

To solve the issue, set height in css for `iron-list`.
For example:

```
iron-list {
      height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: i cannot apply height for iron-list. Though view space has only 50px height approximately.

Comment: If you want to see the whole list, the only way is to increase the height.